# WordPress: $wpdb not deleting from SQL unless put in manually, manually ('2') works with d and s placeholder but not when using $toDELETE

Tags: php, wordpress, forms

I have this:

```
$value = $_POST["check"][0];
$toDELETE = $_POST["itemDELETE" . $value];
$removeFROM = $wpdb->prefix.'plugin_items';
try {
    $wpdb->query($wpdb->prepare("DELETE FROM $removeFROM WHERE itemID = ''.$toDELETE .''"));
    return true;
}
```

It works when I manually put in the ID like this:

```
$value = $_POST["check"][0];
$toDELETE = $_POST["itemDELETE" . $value];
$removeFROM = $wpdb->prefix.'plugin_items';
try {
    $wpdb->query($wpdb->prepare("DELETE FROM $removeFROM WHERE itemID = '2'"));
    return true;
}
```

I can't seem to figure out what exactly I've done wrong. I've also tried
`itemID = $toDELETE"`

This is the input:

```
<input type='checkbox' name='check[]' value='$index' onChange='this.form.submit()' checked='checked'>
<input type='hidden' name='itemDELETE$index' value='$bookID'>
```

When I use `var_export($_POST)` it shows this array:

```
array ( ‘itemDELETE0’ => ‘2’, )
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use placeholder for itemID.

try out this code.

```
 $wpdb->query($wpdb->prepare("DELETE FROM $removeFROM WHERE itemID = %d", $toDELETE));
```

Reference :- https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wpdb/prepare/

Comment: Hi! That line isn't removing it either for some reason. The array is correct when clicked, but it doesn't seem to be properly taking the itemID even with a placeholder for itemID. Thank you so much for replying!

Comment: If I manually put it in with either the placeholder d or s, like so `$wpdb->query($wpdb->prepare("DELETE FROM $removeFROM WHERE itemID = %d", '2'));` it works, but otherwise it won't work

Comment: it means you not getting the value in `$toDELETE`. How you are defining the `$index`.

Comment: Can you check the code above and see if any of it might keep the value from the printed array from getting there? Because when I click the checkbox, the array it prints out with `var_export($_POST)` correctly. Thank you!

Comment: The inputs are within a foreach, which is why the `$value` item is there

Comment: The error is in this line `$_POST["itemDELETE" . $value];` because if I put `$_POST["itemDELETE0]"` it works, but I need to be able to pick up on the index of the item since it's in a foreach array.

Comment: Found the issue, I have another checkbox getting the index and value from a form on the same page, but when I remove that, it works. I just need to figure out a way to make it unique somehow

Comment: This works correctly, the issue I had was something else on the page clashing, thank you!